# How to use Three horizontal bars ☰ menu icon in the iOS App using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, c#-3.0, xamarin-studio

How to use Three horizontal bars ☰ menu icon in the iOS App using Xamarin Forms ?

I am working on XAMARING Forms - Multipage Project. How to use three Horizontal bar icon ?

Comment: [Find the icon online](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/134216/hamburger_lines_menu_icon) and add it to your projects, using [Xamarin's guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Local_Images), along with a good [sizing guide](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change navigating between related pages logic, use Xamarin.Forms master-detail page. Read more: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/